# brew install vim --with-lua is failing

Tags: python, macos, vim, lua, homebrew

I'm using Mac OS Sierra and trying to install vim with lua

```
brew uninstall vim
brew install vim --with-lua
```

It gives me error that a library is missing but i can't find how to install it.

```
env LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.0/lib/perl5/5.26.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE clang   -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib     -o vim objects/arabic.o objects/buffer.o objects/blowfish.o objects/crypt.o objects/crypt_zip.o objects/dict.o objects/diff.o objects/digraph.o objects/edit.o objects/eval.o objects/evalfunc.o objects/ex_cmds.o objects/ex_cmds2.o objects/ex_docmd.o objects/ex_eval.o objects/ex_getln.o objects/farsi.o objects/fileio.o objects/fold.o objects/getchar.o objects/hardcopy.o objects/hashtab.o  objects/if_cscope.o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o objects/list.o objects/mark.o objects/memline.o objects/menu.o objects/misc1.o objects/misc2.o objects/move.o objects/mbyte.o objects/normal.o objects/ops.o objects/option.o objects/os_unix.o objects/pathdef.o objects/popupmnu.o objects/pty.o objects/quickfix.o objects/regexp.o objects/screen.o objects/search.o objects/sha256.o objects/spell.o objects/spellfile.o objects/syntax.o objects/tag.o objects/term.o objects/terminal.o objects/ui.o objects/undo.o objects/userfunc.o objects/version.o objects/window.o  objects/term_encoding.o objects/term_keyboard.o objects/term_mouse.o objects/term_parser.o objects/term_pen.o objects/term_screen.o objects/term_state.o objects/term_unicode.o objects/term_vterm.o objects/if_lua.o  objects/if_perl.o objects/if_perlsfio.o objects/if_python.o   objects/if_ruby.o objects/os_macosx.o objects/os_mac_conv.o  objects/netbeans.o objects/channel.o  objects/charset.o objects/json.o objects/main.o objects/memfile.o objects/message.o        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa  -L/usr/local/lib -llua -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.0/lib/perl5/5.26.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lm -lutil -lc -F/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks -framework Python   -lruby.2.4.1 -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
ld: library not found for -lruby.2.4.1
```

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/p3h2gg/brew-install-vim-with-lua-support

Comment: Please report this to the Homebrew folks: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting.html

Comment: Try to install lua in macvim first: brew install macvim --with-lua. After that, you can continue with: brew install vim --with-lua

Comment: @diek thanks, that helped

Answer (score 2):

If you have ruby2.5.1 already installed skip step 1:

1. \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=2.5.1
2. brew link --overwrite ruby
3. brew install vim --with-lua --with-override-system-vi